# C++ - Switching from G++ to Xcode (and clang)

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, clang

I'm trying to use a [sample program](https://github.com/knatten/blog.knatten.org/blob/master/gloox/bot.cpp) for the `gloox` library (a XMPP client library for C++) that I'll eventually integrate into (among others) an iOS app. An obvious (yet frustrating difficult) step in achieving this is to use the C++ code in Xcode (typically with the clang compiler).

How I compiled using `G++`:

`g++ -o bot bot.cpp -lgloox -lpthread`

What I've tried in `Xcode`:

Under my targets build settings:

- Went to `Other C++ Flags` and added `-lpthread` and `-lgloox`, so in theory the required libraries are linked.
- Went to `Header Search Paths` and added `/usr/include` and `/usr/local/include`, both set to `recursive.` The gloox headers are found in `/usr/local/include`, so the header should theoretically be available.

However, when I go to compile this abomination, I get these errors:

[image]

Can somebody help me make sense of these?

**Edit:** I've searched the internet extensively for this, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to *remove* `/usr/include` from your library search paths. It's already included by default, and trying to add it a second time can make it end up overriding some headers provided by the compiler, with unfortunate results.

---

[The link errors you got when you did this](http://cl.ly/image/220M0Q2p0L0C) look like the gloox library isn't being used at link time, so that's failing now. *This is progress!* — if you're getting to the link phase, compilation is now going just fine.

Go to your project settings (click the project name at the top of the left-hand column), go to the "Build Phases" tab, open up the "Link Binary With Libraries" phase, and click the + button. Then find `libgloox.dylib` (probably in `/usr/local/lib`) and add it.

Comment: :O YES! What's a .dylib file? I'm a don't understand why libraries need more than header/implementation files. I don't get the why all required library files can't just be `#include`ed =/

Comment: The `.dylib` is the actual library file, where all the code is. The header files just describe to the compiler how it's used.